# Validator crashes if --bind-address present in start script

Tags: solana-program

Got a trouble trying set `--bind-address` on my validator configuration. My node has a lot of additional IPs. When I try to bind validator to one of them, system says that all required ports are open, but validtor crashes with this in log:

```
[2024-01-21T02:33:32.888983711Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that tcp ports [(8899, TcpListener { addr: <my IP>:8899, fd: 83 }), (8900, TcpListener { addr: <my IP>:8900, fd: 84 }), (8000, TcpListener { addr: <my IP>:8000, fd: 85 })] are reachable from 145.40.93.177:8001
[2024-01-21T02:33:38.152091781Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2024-01-21T02:33:43.152551059Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8900, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2024-01-21T02:33:48.153066421Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8000, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
```

Removing `--bind-address` from start parameters makes validator running as expected.
System shows necessary ports as open, but validator program doesn't response on this ports. Output of `netstat -tnlp` command is below:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name    
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 27497/systemd-resol 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22    0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 42919/sshd: /usr/sb 
tcp 0 0 <my IP>:8000  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 538091/solana-valid 
tcp 0 0 <my IP>:8899  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 538091/solana-valid 
tcp 0 0 <my IP>:8900  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 538091/solana-valid 
tcp6 0 0 :::22             :::* LISTEN 42919/sshd: /usr/sb
```

Version of Solana is 1.17.16. IP is active, pingable but hidden here for security reasons. Is the bug or something else?